# How to access Promise like below example in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I want to access Promisse values from below Promise type

```
Promise
    __proto__:Promise
    [[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
    [[PromiseValue]]:Object
        currentlySending:false
        errorMessage:Object
        loggedIn:true
        user:Object
        __proto__:Object
```

This is when i get above output.

```
var data = sessionService.loadUser();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the promise is already in `data`, but what do you mean by accessing it? Did you try `data.then(func)`

Comment: I want to access user object from promise but don't know how i can?I tries with console.log(data.user); but giving undefined

Comment: It seems you are looking for [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

Comment: on using .then() it gives Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined} .

Comment: the result is async so .then has a callback sessionService.loadUser().then(function(data){ ... access here ... })

Comment: i console.log data same you have mentioned nothing is on console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve your promise using [**then**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
sessionService.loadUser().then(function(value) {
   console.log(value); // <- your promise data exists here.
}, catch(error) {
   console.error(error); // <- promise resolved with error.
});
```

Regardless of whether you get your data in the `then` block, or `catch` an error instead; by doing this you will have a much better idea of what is going on with your promise.

Comment: Nothing is on console

Comment: try doing this: `console.log(sessionService.loadUser());` the reason I say that is I want you to make sure that `loadUser()` returns a `Promise` or an object of type `Promise`. If that is true we can look at using `then` to resolve the promise.

Comment: Its return promise only same as mentioned in question description

Comment: I have also tried sessionService.loadUser().then(function(data){console.log('into then');}).then(function(data){
            console.log('into then 1');
            console.log(data);
        });

Comment: Have you debugged your code to inspect everything? Such as is your `sessionService` being used, is the value of `loadUser()` accessible, defined, not unknown? Is it a `Promise`?

Comment: i am using sessionService in only one component and i try to debug it all over
I have raised on new question which is actualy i need to work on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336915/redux-react-session-how-to-get-user-info-into-state-on-refresh

Comment: Good morning, I just saw the question you posted and you did get an answer. So do you have an update?

Comment: AGE not any answer